# Background color c# interpo

Tags: c#, excel

I am using Visual Studio C# and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` I can't get the good color from cell in excel sheet. My question is: how I can get background color from cell.

I tried this code :

```
var bachgroundColor = ws.Cells[7, 3].Interior.Color;
```

but the result is: `System___ComObject`

Answer (score 0):

The major issue with Interop is that DDE mechanism works fine some times. But many time the data exchange will be affected and you loss data without error or warning alert or exception.There is nice lib called EPPlus, that makes your relationships with excel much easier and secure. You can find it on NuGet.

```
Color CellColor = sheet.Cells[x, y].Interior.Color;
```

[Change Cell Font and Background Color](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/12357/spreadsheet-document-api/examples/formatting/how-to-change-cell-font-and-background-color)

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get the int value of the Interior Color. And then convert it to type "Color".

Here is a demo you can refer to.

```
string strFileName = @"D:\test.xls";
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workBook = excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(strFileName, missing, true, missing, missing, missing,
missing, missing, missing, true, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Sheets[1];

int colorNumber = System.Convert.ToInt32(((Range)worksheet.Cells[1, 2]).Interior.Color);
Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(colorNumber);
//this.BackColor = color;
```